# How can one prove that the Moore Penrose limit exists?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let, $A \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$. Let,

$$x_\alpha = (A^{*}A + \alpha^2I)^{-1}A^{*}, \alpha \in \mathbb{R}.$$
How would one prove that,
$$\lim_{\alpha \rightarrow 0} x_{\alpha},$$
exists? I know that we can obtain:
$$||x_{\alpha}|| \le ||A||*||(A^{*}A+ \alpha^2I)^{-1}||, $$
but I do not know where to go from here. I thought or possibly defining,
$$T(\alpha) = (A^{*}A + \alpha^2 I)^{-1}A^{*},$$
and then prove it is a linear operator and then show that it is bounded, but it is obviously not a linear operator so this route does not work.
Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio, no, thank you for bringing that to my attention.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $A = U\Sigma V^*$ be a [singular value decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition) of $A$, that is, $U$ and $V$ are unitary matrices and $\Sigma$ is a diagonal matrix with non-negative diagonal entries $\sigma_1,\ldots, \sigma_n$. Then

\begin{align*}
(A^*A + \alpha^2 I)^{-1}A^*
&= (V\Sigma^2 V^* + \alpha^2 I)^{-1} V \Sigma U^* \\
&= V(\Sigma^2 + \alpha^2 I)^{-1} \Sigma U^* \\
&= V \operatorname{diag}(f_{\alpha}(\sigma_1), \ldots, f_{\alpha}(\sigma_n)) U^*,
\end{align*}

where $f_{\alpha}(\sigma) = \dfrac{\sigma}{\sigma^2 + \alpha^2}$. Now the crucial observation is that $f_{\alpha}$ converges pointwise everywhere as $\alpha \to 0$:

$$ f_0(\sigma)
:= \lim_{\alpha \to 0} f_{\alpha}(\sigma)
= \begin{cases}
0, & \sigma = 0, \\
\sigma^{-1}, & \sigma \neq 0.
\end{cases} $$

This shows that the desired limit exist with the value:

\begin{align*}
\lim_{\alpha \to 0} (A^*A + \alpha^2 I)^{-1}A^*
&= V \operatorname{diag}(f_0(\sigma_1), \ldots, f_0(\sigma_n)) U^*.
\end{align*}